# s3.putObject() blocking server while listening to httpDownloadProgress event

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm running an https server via node.js. I'm using amazon s3 to store some files. I'm using aws-sdk-js as a node module.

Here's the code I use to upload something on my server:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.loadFromPath('./AwsConfig.json');
var s3 = new aws.S3();

s3.putObject({
    ACL: 'public-read',
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: remoteFilename,
    Body: fileBuffer,
    ContentType: metaData
}, function (err, obj) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else {
        console.log('uploaded file[' + path + '] to [' + remoteFilename + '] as [' + metaData + ']');
    }
}).on('httpUploadProgress', function(progress) {
    console.log('Upload', progress.loaded, 'of' , progress.total, 'bytes');
});
```

I get the files properly, however during upload I can't access anything on my site. I believe during upload its blocking any activity on my server. I thought this code is asynchronous, but I guess not.

Any advice on how to prevent this block?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but couldn't you just wrap it in a setTimeout to make it asynchronous?:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    s3.putObject({
        ACL: 'public-read',
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: remoteFilename,
        Body: fileBuffer,
        ContentType: metaData
    }, function (err, obj) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else {
            console.log('uploaded file[' + path + '] to [' + remoteFilename + '] as [' + metaData + ']');
        }
    }).on('httpUploadProgress', function(progress) {
        console.log('Upload', progress.loaded, 'of' , progress.total, 'bytes');
    });
}, 0);
```

Let me know if that works!